# How to disable or set lock for quick settings menu on Realme 3?

Tags: password, quick-settings, realme

I am using Realme 3. I would like to restrict the quick settings icon from being used so that when the user clicks on the quick settings icon, the mobile should ask for a password.

What is the way to disable the quick settings icon or set a lock for that icon?

Comment: @Andrew can you please help me in this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any experiences or suggestions in this situation...